# Python: Subclassing frozenset not iterable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, types, set, subclassing

Subclassing frozenset and set doesn't seem to work the same when it comes to iterables. Try to run the following MWE:

```
class MonFrozenSet(frozenset):
    def __new__(self, data):
        super(MonFrozenSet,self).__init__(data)
        return self

class MonSet(set):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(MonSet,self).__init__(data)



x=(1,2,3,4)

A=MonSet(x)
B=MonFrozenSet(x)

for y in A: #Works
    print y

for y in B: #Doesn't work
    print y
```

The second `for` returns:

```
for y in B:
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

Any idea on how I can solve this?

If you are asking yourselves why I would like to use frozenset, the anwer is that I am trying to create a set of sets of tuples. The sets of tuples will be frozenset and the set of sets of tuples will be a set.

I use Python-2.7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When overriding `__new__` you need to call the superclass's `__new__`, not its `__init__`.  Also, you need to pass `self` (better named `cls`), since `__new__` is a classmethod.  Also, you need to return the result, since `__new__` actually creates an object, it doesn't modify `self`.  So:

```
class MonFrozenSet(frozenset):
    def __new__(cls, data):
        return super(MonFrozenSet,cls).__new__(cls, data)
```

Then:

```
>>> a = MonFrozenSet([1, 2, 3])
>>> for item in a:
...     print item
1
2
3
```